# ShellExecute doesn't work for other computer

Tags: c++, winapi, release, shellexecute

I made a program using Win32Api. In the program, it has "ShellExecute" phrase in order to execute chrome for searching. 
Following is a abstraction fo what i wrote.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
int main () {
    ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", searching_url, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
}
```

It works in my computer. But, I sent this windows app to other people and they said it doesn't work. I mean only shellexecute doesn't work. I cannot catch where to start figuring out what's wrong here.

Would you please suggest How I figure it out in structured way?
Thanks.

Comment: Check the return value (have your program display it and get the other people to tell you what it is), this will give you more info about why execution failed.  [Reference for return value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @M.M return value from ShellExecute is probably useless. To get proper error handling use ShellExecuteEx.

Comment: Does ShellExecute show an error ? Did you check the return value of ShellExecute?

Comment: Thanks for all comments and answers. I changed L"open" to NULL and it works out ! But still I'm not sure why it did in that way.

Comment: Because as Jonathan Potter pointed, is possible that verb "open" not exist.

Answer (score 5):

Two things to try:

- ShellExecute can require COM to be initialized under certain circumstances. The [docs for the `ShellExecute` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) explain why in more detail. You should call `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE)` before the call to `ShellExecute` and `CoUninitialize()` afterwards.
- Instead of using `L"open"` as the verb, you should generally use `NULL`. `NULL` will always give you the "default" action for an object (equivalent to double-clicking it) which is not always "open".